# Clojure where is left fold

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, fold

Does clojure implement left fold or right fold?

I understand there is a new library reducers which has this but shouldn't it exists in clojure.core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clojure implements a left fold called `reduce`.

Why no right fold?

- `reduce` and many other functions work on *sequence*s, which are
  accessible from the left but not the right.

The new reducers and transducers are designed to work with associative functions on data structures of varying accessibility.

Comment: You don't need to access a sequence from the right to implement a right fold: `(defn reduce-right [f init xs] (if-let [xs (seq xs)] (f (first xs) (reduce-right (rest xs) f init)) init))`.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, you *can* implement right-fold this way, but the JVM and hence Clojure, with fairly constrained stack space, are ill-equipped to handle recursing through a long sequence. For example, `(reduce-right max -1 (range 10000))` induces stack overflow here - YMMV. [To get this result, I corrected your function to call itself consistently and took the chance to simplify it a little: `(defn reduce-right [f init xs] (if (seq xs) (f (first xs) (reduce-right f init (lazy-seq (rest xs)))) init))`.]

Answer (score 0):

As Thumbnail points out, reduce-right cannot be efficiently implemented on the jvm for sequences. But as it turns out, we do have a family of data types that can do efficient lookup and truncation from the right side. reduce-right can be implemented for vectors.

```
user> 
(defn reduce-right
  [f init vec]
  (loop [acc init v vec]
    (if (empty? v)
      acc
      (recur (f acc (peek v)) (pop v)))))

#'user/reduce-right
user> (count (str (reduce-right *' 1 (into [] (range 1 100000))))) ; digit count
456569
```

Comment: According to where `peek` and `pop` operate, this does a right-fold on vectors but a left-fold on lists: `(reduce-right (fn [_ x] x) :init (vec (range 10)))` => `0`; `(reduce-right (fn [_ x] x) :init (apply list (range 10)))` => `9`.

Comment: Yeah, not meant for lists at all. A precondition could be called for I guess.